# Disambiguating std::isalpha() in C++

Tags: c++, std, sfml

So I am currently writing a part of a program that takes user text input.  I want to ignore all input characters that are not alphabetic, and so I figured std::isalpha() would be a good way to do this.  Unfortunately, as far as I know there are two std::isalpha() functions, and the general one needs to be disambiguated from the locale-specific one thusly:

```
(int(*)(int))std::isalpha()
```

If I don't disambiguate, std::isalpha seems to return true when reading uppercase but false when reading lowercase letters (if I directly print the returned value, though, it returns 0 for non-alpha chars, 1 for uppercase chars, and 2 for lowercase chars). So I need to do this.

I've done so in another program before, but for some reason, in this project, I sometimes get "ISO C++ forbids" errors.  Note, only sometimes.  Here is the problematic area of code (this appears together without anything in between):

```
std::cout << "Is alpha? " << (int(*)(int))std::isalpha((char)Event.text.unicode) << "\n";

if ( (int(*)(int))std::isalpha((char)Event.text.unicode) == true)
{
    std::cout << "Is alpha!\n";
    //...snip...
}
```

The first instance, where I send the returned value to std::cout, works fine - I get no errors for this, I get the expected values (0 for non-alpha, 1 for alpha), and if that's the only place I try to disambiguate, the program compiles and runs fine.

The second instance, however, throws up this:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
```

and only compiles if I remove the (int(*)(int)) snippet, at which point bad behavior ensues.  Could someone enlighten me here?

Comment: Why do you perform the comparison `== true`?  Don't do that. It's redundant from a readability standpoint and causes problems when comparing with a result that can be non-zero to indicate 'truth'.

Comment: Can you please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) of the problem? I've only had to apply the cast to `is*` functions to disambiguate them from their locale aware counterparts when passing the functions around as predicates to algorithms, not in the use case you're describing.

Comment: Hm, bad habit I suppose.  I've just removed it and now it compiles AND works fine, so thanks!  But I don't really understand why, though.  Even if the return type is int, wouldn't you be able to compare it with a bool anyway, and all non-zero values would be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting *the return value* of the `std::alpha()` call to `int(*)(int)`, and then compare that pointer to `true`. Comparing pointers to boolean values doesn't make much sense and you get an error.

Now, without the cast, you compare the `int` returned by `std::alpha()` to `true`. `bool` is an integer type, and to compare the two different integer types the values are first converted to the same type. In this case they are both converted to `int`. `true` becomes `1`, and if `std::isalpha()` returned `2` the comparison ends up with `2 != 1`.

If you want to compare the result of `std::alpha()` against a `bool`, you should cast that returned in to `bool`, or simply leave out the comparison and use something like `if (std::isalpha(c)) {...}`

Comment: But isn't anything within the parentheses of if() compared to true if not otherwise specified?

Comment: Ah, thank you for the explanation re: boolean and integer comparison!  Now I understand.

Comment: huh? I thought std::isalpha returns a boolean? - thats what http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/isalpha/ says. (and why do you discuss std::alpha in the answer)

Comment: @Tom You're linking to the locale-specific function, but I was using this one: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isalpha/

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to disambiguate, because the there is no ambiguity in a normal call.

Also, there is no need to use the `std::` prefix when you get the function declaration from `<ctype.h>`, which after C++11 is the header you should preferably use (i.e., not `<cctype>`) – and for that matter also before C++11, but C++11 clinched it.

Third, you should not compare the result to `true`.

However, you need to cast a `char` argument to `unsigned char`, lest you get Undefined Behavior for anything but 7-bit ASCII.

E.g. do like this:

```
bool isAlpha( char const c )
{
    typedef unsigned char UChar;
    return !!isalpha( UChar( c ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip concerning Undefined Behavior, I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with using std::isalpha?  Why use the c and not the c++ function?  Indeed, I thought std::isalpha guaranteed returning a bool.

Comment: @Tom: there's nothing *wrong* with using `std::isalpha`. you just run an increased risk of the code not working with some other compiler or in some other context, because the declaration might be coming from a [.h] header like `<ctype.h>`, which is permitted to drop the name also in the `std` namespace. you're right to ask about this, but you could also have searched SO. `std::isalpha` has [two overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha). one returns `int`, the other `bool`. this, however, was wrong to ask about. you should just have checked the documentation for this. ;-)

Comment: @Tom: re "why use the c and not the c++ function", well the two main reasons are simplicity and efficiency. the c++ take on locales is not something a c++ programmer is very proud of. as i see it, it is over-engineered, limited, extremely complicated, brittle, lacking in functionality, and historically *not even supported* by e.g. g++ in Windows. i haven't checked how it is with g++ 4.7.1 in windows. but it wouldn't surprise me if it is that way still. so...